# Errors when running `apt update`. W: NO PUB_KEY and W:Target package is configured multiple times

Tags: apt, updates

When I try to update my system with `sudo apt-get update`, I receive the following:

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:3 http://pkg.scaleft.com/deb linux InRelease [4808 B]
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Err:3 http://pkg.scaleft.com/deb linux InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F716E939977FC428
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://pkg.scaleft.com/deb linux InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F716E939977FC428
E: The repository 'http://pkg.scaleft.com/deb linux InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
```

How can I fix this and update my system?

#### EDIT

Now, I am getting:

```
root@PYAMMANO-68J9Z:/# echo "deb http://pkg.scaleft.com/deb linux main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://pkg.scaleft.com/deb linux main
root@PYAMMANO-68J9Z:/# curl -fsSL https://dist.scaleft.com/pki/scaleft_deb_key.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/scaleft-archive-keyring.gpg > /dev/null
root@PYAMMANO-68J9Z:/# apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 95 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up scaleft-server-tools (1.56.1) ...
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
dpkg: error processing package scaleft-server-tools (--configure):
 installed scaleft-server-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 scaleft-server-tools
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scaleft.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scaleft.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scaleft.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scaleft.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:50 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scaleft.list:1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your question in the body of the question and apply formatting code for any code you include. Currently, the question cannot be read.

Comment: Based on the message, you will want to fix your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to remove duplicate lines. This can be done by putting a `#` at the start of a line with a duplicate, or removing it altogether. Once done, you will be able to update and upgrade correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There are three errors in your system.

- First, one of your repositories is not signed and requires a GPG key.
- Secondly, your `sources.list` has duplicate sources.
- Third, your system has a corrupted package.

Adding the proper signatures.

1. Run the following command in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F716E939977FC428
   ```
2. Update:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

Fixing the duplicate entries.

1. Install the `Y-PPA-MANAGER`:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
   sudo apt upgrade
   sudo apt install y-ppa-manager
   ```
2. Open the `Y-PPA-MANAGER`:

   ```
   sudo y-ppa-manager
   ```

   [image: Y PPA MANAGER]
3. Navigate to *Advanced → Scan and remove duplicate PPAs*.

   [image: Advanced options.]
4. Let it complete and run:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

To fix the corrupted package:

1. First, update the repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Now, run:

   ```
   sudo apt download runit-systemd && sudo dpkg -i --force-all ./*.deb
   ```
3. Run force install:

   ```
   sudo apt -f install
   ```

   This will also install the package you wanted to install i.e `scaleft-server-tools`.

If you want you can purge reinstall the package. By running:

```
sudo dpkg -P scaleft-server-tools --force-all && sudo apt install scaleft-server-tools
```

Alternatively, you can manually edit the post-installation files for the package `scaleft-server-tools` and replace the `systemctl` command with the `service` command and run `sudo apt -f install`.
Reboot to confirm all the changes.

That's it! 
Good Luck!

#### EDIT

For problem #3 i.e Corrupted package.

In the documentation, I found that for Ubuntu 20.04 Focal or above, you need to explicitly allow certificate authorities (CAs) to use the ssh-rsa algorithm to sign certificates.

To do this, you need to add the following line to your OpenSSH daemon file (which is either `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or a drop-in file under `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/`):

```
CASignatureAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Comment: Just step 1 and 2 did the trick for me, a lifesaver answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions on [Okta.com](https://help.okta.com/asa/en-us/Content/Topics/Adv_Server_Access/docs/sft-ubuntu.htm) (formatting, my own):

> 2.Trust the repository signing key:
>
> ```
> curl -fsSL https://dist.scaleft.com/pki/scaleft_deb_key.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/scaleft-archive-keyring.gpg > /dev/null
> ```

after you've installed the certificate, you might need to `apt -f install` to fix any installation you've tried to do already, but then hopefully everything else will install happily.